# get latest visitors on site

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called 'traffic' that I use to log website visitors.

Every page view is logged, so I have multiple entries per IP address.

I need to retrieve the latest visit grouped by IP address. How can I do this?

Columns: id (autoinc), ipaddress (varchar), lastActivity(datetime)

Comment: 1. Are you sure this is legal? 2. IP address can't be coupled to visitor. 3. `SELECT ipaddress FROM traffic ORDER BY lastActivity DESC LIMIT 1;`

Answer (score 1):

```
select f.ipaddress , f.lastActivity 
from (
   select ipaddress , max(lastActivity) as maxdate
   from traffic group by ipaddress ) as x
   inner join traffic as f 
   on f.ipaddress = x.ipaddress and f.lastActivity= x.maxdate;
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Unfortunately I can't vote this up as I'm a new member. But thank you very much!

Comment: @Bondye Joining a table to itself is a very useful technique.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Self-join

Comment: @DavidGorsline But it's not the solution of this problem. He only want to get the latest visitor. So its easy to do with `ORDER BY lastActivity DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: @Bondye: This is not as simple as you thought it is. If you read the question carefully, you can understand it would not work with your suggestion. Read the Json's comment on Shamim's answer.

Comment: @Bondye:When you get that the answer is okay, please revert the downvote I am editing my answer to allow you the same.

Comment: @ShaktiSingh Removed downvote ;) Shame they call you Mr. Singh.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select * from traffic GROUP BY ipaddress ORDER BY lastActivity DESC
```

Comment: in the above query order by will work on grouped result. so this does not return desired result

Comment: Doesn't work. Mr Singh is right. I just want the "latest" visit of each iPaddress. The above query simply groups them in random order and then applies order afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gunner. Appreciate your input.